# How to remove all NaN columns for each subcategory?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python pandas dataframe of this sort with large number of columns and rows. I want to remove all columns with NaN for each subcategory which belong to the same category. How can I remove all the NaN columns for each of the subcategories?

```
     Categ. Subcat. cond1 cond2 cond3 cond4 condk
0    A          k     NaN   6     4     9     8
1    A          k     NaN   7     3     NaN   2
2    A          p      8    1     NaN   NaN   3
3    A          s      4    NaN   2     8     NaN
4    A          t     NaN   3     NaN   4     1
5    A          t      2    9     NaN   5     4
```

After removing cond1 for Subcat. k, the output dataframe should look like this. I have many columns that contain all NaN for a subcategory. For e.g. subcat. k has let’s say 10 columns/cond1,cond5, cond9, con20,etc/ with NaN as their value for this particular subcat.

```
Categ. Subcat. cond2 cond3 cond4...condk 
A          k      6    4     9     8 
A          k      7    3    NaN    2
A          p      1   NaN   NaN    3
A          s     NaN   2     8    NaN 
A          t      3   NaN    4     1 
A          t      9   NaN    5     4
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the output you'd like?  I'm a little unclear on exactly what you want.  And if you have any code you've tried, posting that (or a brief extract of that) will help people see where you've gone wrong.

Comment: what you're asking seem like it will end up with NO columns at all in the end if there is at least one NaN in each column.

Comment: Could you rather describe what you're trying to get to, i.e. why do you need to remove NaN, as opposed to replacing them?
or are you trying to simply aggregate what conditions are present for each column, in which case you probably want to end up with a single column array with the valid conditions

Comment: The objective is to reduce the number of columns for each subcat. that belong to a category. I have a small number of categories each having n number of subcategories.

Comment: Is that the *final* output you want, or just the output after performing the operation for Subcategory `k`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example DataFrame so it is copyable:

```
     Categ. Subcat. cond1 cond2 cond3 cond4 condk
0    A          k     NaN   6     4     9     8
1    A          k     NaN   7     3     NaN   2
2    A          p      8    1     NaN   NaN   3
3    A          s      4    NaN   2     8     NaN
4    A          t     NaN   3     NaN   4     1
5    A          t      2    9     NaN   5     4

df = df.rename(columns={'Categ.':'C', 'Subcat.':'S'})
```

You can groupby like this: `gb = df.groupby('S')`

Then:

```
for n, g in gb:
    print(n, '\n', g.dropna(axis=1))
k
    C  S  cond2  cond3  condk
0  A  k    6.0    4.0    8.0
1  A  k    7.0    3.0    2.0
p
    C  S  cond1  cond2  condk
2  A  p    8.0    1.0    3.0
s
    C  S  cond1  cond3  cond4
3  A  s    4.0    2.0    8.0
t
    C  S  cond2  cond4  condk
4  A  t    3.0    4.0    1.0
5  A  t    9.0    5.0    4.0
```

It's not really clear how you want to remove rows/Series from the DataFrame, but this should give you a start...

Comment: Thank you Alex. That works. My next newbie question is how do I store the out put into a separate DataFrame? Dataframe for k, p, and t each.

Comment: You need to provide some indication of what you expect. The groups could be combined but you'll just end up with NaN wherever columns do not match.

Comment: for n, g in gb:
    s_df = g.dropna(axis=1), how = 'all') # Removes all null cols for a sub.
    break
s_df # This prints DataFrame for only one of the subcateg.(k). I want to display for eacch and every subcateg one by one for k, t, and s. How Can I achieve that?